# SalesForce.com Rest API Authentication. Will it allow 2-legged oauth transaction

Tags: oauth, salesforce

SalesForce.com Rest API Authentication. Will it allow 2-legged oauth transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does allow 2-legged authentication, although Salesforce docs say that it isn't recommended. It's described in detail here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

From using it I know it always redirects you to salesforce to login and authorise the application, which if I have my terminology right is 3-legged oAuth, so at this point in time I'd say it doesn't support that.

[THere's some good information on oAuth and Salesforce here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual support page for Salesforce 2 legged Oauth:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Contrary to another answer it is recommended and supported as long as you use the above method.

aka:
OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration